# stretch the svg circle as per window resize using transform matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm using svg circle in my application. I need to resize the circle when window is resized, i'm getting this feature from setting viewbox for my svg but i need to use the transform attribute. I have searched a lot about transform and i got "matrix" for my application but i can't resize it as per window resized, i want to know how to calculate the matrix values as per window size when window is resized dynamically and also i'm still confused in matrix values. and this is my svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="true" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" r="50" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
```

I have created a [DEMO HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Vs4/2/)
Any suggestions should be appreciated.

**NOTE:** In this demo the circle will not resize

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `viewBox`?

Comment: BTW: `true` is not a valid value for `preserveAspectRatio`

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your demo if you give your circle an `id="circle"` attribute

```
var originalBBox = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var newBBox = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();
    circle.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.a = newBBox.width / originalBBox.width;
    circle.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.d = newBBox.height / originalBBox.height;
}, true);
```